# Ionic unit testing with slides throws TypeError

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework

I have a component that references my `ion-slides` which is throwing an error during component initialization:

```
<ion-content class="blue-purple-gradient" [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-slides pager="true" #slides>
    ...
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

export class ReEvaluationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(IonSlides, {static: false}) slides: IonSlides;

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.slides) {
      this.slides.lockSwipeToNext(true)
    }
  }
}
```

This throws the following error when running a test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
```

Here is the test:

```
describe('ReEvaluationComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    NavParamsMock.setParams({
      client: {dob: "1991-01-22"}
    })
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ReEvaluationComponent ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        SharedModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: Storage, useValue: storageMock},
        {provide: NavParams, useValue: navParams},
        {provide: WeighInsProvider, useValue: weighInsServiceMock},
        {provide: GlobalsService, useValue: mockGlobalsService},
        {provide: TransactionsProvider, useValue: transactionsServiceMock},
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    injector = getTestBed()
    checkInsService = injector.get(CheckInsProvider)
    weighInsService = injector.get(WeighInsProvider)
    transactionsService = injector.get(TransactionsProvider)
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReEvaluationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  })

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ion-slides is going to be deprecated in the next ionic version, so instead of trying to implement it like you are doing, I'd suggest to migrate to Swiper who is going to be our next 'ion-slide' and won't get you in that much trouble.

If you want to know more about it:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#migration

You can check this video explaining the use:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcvieKvmI5A

Or follow this tutorial:

https://ionicacademy.com/swiper-with-ionic/